# Unable to select an angular dropdown menu using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to select a dropdown value in my app built in Angular. Here are my observations:

- There is a select tag present in the dom with options tag underneath that. I tried making use of the select class to select the dropdown options and I was not successful. On inspecting the element, I learned that the element is hidden. Attaching the screenshot of the select element[image]
- I tried accessing the element with id "Location_chosen" and the elements beneath that as well ( a, span div, b). However each time I received an error, the element is not clickable at that point and some other element would receive the click.
- identifier - css_Selector - #Location_chosen a - Operation - `element.click()` - Error - Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (1677, 462)
- identifier - css_Selector - #Location_chosen a span - Operation - `element.click()` - Error - Message: element click intercepted: `Element <span style="border: none;">...</span> is not clickable at point (806, 463). Other element would receive the click: <div class="row display-flex m-l-5 ng-scope ng-enter-prepare" style="font-weight : bold" ng-repeat="formRow in dynamicForm.components ">...</div>`
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.122) . Now the element that is expected to be clicked in this exception is in a complete different row of the user form. Also, please note that I have used an explicit wait statement for the element to be clickable and no exception was thrown. But, after that element click is not working.
  [image]

Comment: I have tried javascript click and actions click on the above elements as well. I couldn't click on the element

Comment: please post your code sample(what you have tried so far)

Comment: It can be that drop-down web element is not visible, until you open it.

Comment: I have tried 
`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)`
`element.click`
`action.move_to_element(web_element).click(web_element).perform()`

Comment: I had installed Katalon recorder to record the ui operations through record and playback feature. 

Below is the code generated :
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='Location_chosen']/a/span").click()
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='Location_chosen']/div/ul/li").click()
    `
This code worked when I played back the recorded script. however, when I used the same locator with my test scripts , it throws Elementclickintercepted exception.